# Phaser 3: call canvas texture from another file

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, textures, phaser-framework

I am trying to convert this post to phaser 3: https://phaser.io/tutorials/coding-tips-002
but the update() function not working. In file a.ts I create a canvas texture:

```
this.textures1 = this.textures.createCanvas('canvastextures1', 450, 170)
this.land1 = this.textures.get(MAPOPTIONS.BASE1_NAME).getSourceImage()
this.textures1.draw(0, 0, this.land1)
this.textures1.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'
```

and in file b.ts, in overlap() function:

```
  this.activeTextures = this.textures.get('canvastextures1')
  this.activeTextures.context.beginPath()
  this.activeTextures.context.arc(Math.floor(overlap2.x-tile.getTopLeft().x), Math.floor(overlap2.y-tile.getTopLeft().y), 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
  this.activeTextures.context.fill()
  this.activeTextures.update()
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: can you share more code, details? how are you _importing_ the `b.ts` file into the `a.ts`? Don't forget the stackoverflow Motto: _Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem._  For help with this, checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi winner_joiner, I have added some code in the post

Comment: hello CS No.1, I wrote an answer based on your code I hope it helps.

Comment: I have edited the post, the problem is update() function not working

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could call a function from a different `scene`, where the texture is created. Checkout this example, to see how calling a function from a different `scene` looks like: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/call-function-in-another-scene#
*(I'm, assuming the mentioned files `a.ts` and `b.ts` are different scenes).*

**Basically you just have to:**

- In the file b.ts (or where you want to use the texture) get the scene, that contatins the function, which generates the texture. For example, like this: `var sceneA = this.scene.get('sceneA');`
- and than call the function on that `scene`, for example like this `var value = sceneA.generateMyTexture();`
- finally you can call `this.textures.get('canvastextures1')`, or just return the needed object/data from the function, depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks, winner_joiner, but I have edited the post to more clearly.

Comment: @CSNo.1 I'm sorry, but I still don't  understand the problem and how you spilt this into two files? Why is not everything in on file / one scene? are you using two scenes, which one is main /running one? is there an error message?

Comment: the problem is I can not use update() function. As the tips I following, when a bullet overlap land, I will change canvas texture to "erase" mode, draw a hole, and use update() function for the texture, if the update() not working, when the bullet overlap the land at the same position, it will not create a deeper hole. I split into multiple files for my own structure. You can refer the link in my post, try disable update() function for more clearly my trouble